# How to query the values in a jsonb column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

Given a `jsonb` column called `pairs` with data such as the following in a single record:

```
{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }
```

How to query for records where a given value is one of the ***values*** in the above field.

For example, query for 1 would match the above record.
Query for 3 would not match.

PostgreSQL 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres 9.5 use the function `jsonb_each_text()` in a lateral join:

```
with my_table(pairs) as (
values 
    ('{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }'::jsonb)
)

select t.*
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_each_text(pairs)
where value = '1';
```

Upgrade to Postgres 12 and use json path functions, e.g.:

```
select *
from my_table
where jsonb_path_exists(pairs, '$.* ? (@ == 1)')
```

Read more: [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: Is it possible to do this in PostgreSQL 9.5 without the `with` and `cross join` clauses? Only using `select` and `left join` or `inner join`?

Comment: The `with` statement is not necessary, in this example it is like your original table. The `cross join` does not mean the Cartesian product here because it is a lateral join. But you can replace it with `left join` if you wish. See [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=496092f501ca73db3170797b65fec2eb)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do it in Postgres 9.5 without a JOIN? That is, with only a WHERE clause?

Comment: Practically not. If you have a primary key (or a unique column) you can try to use `jsonb_each_text()` in a `WHERE` clause but the lateral join is simpler and faster. The main point is that there is no function in 9.5 like `jsonb_path_exists()`, so you have to use the set returning function `jsonb_each_text()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!